# Android ListFragment cannot populate from async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I've been bashing my head against a wall on this for about a day now. I hope someone can help.

My program loads and parses some Json in to an array of objects in an async task. This async task is called from my ListFragment class and the data is sent back in the onPostExecute. No errors are thrown and the list loading animation disappears as it should. But no matter what I do the list is never populated.

I'm definitely getting data returned and parsed correctly and I've tried using a simple array and adapter in the onPostExecute to make sure it's not my adapter class and it still doesn't work.

I've simplified my code below to just an example. The code below waits for 1 second then removes the loading animation. But doesn't populate the list. If you remove the sleep from the doInBackground method it works perfectly.

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>()
            {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               

                    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                              "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                              "Linux", "OS/2" };

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                }           

     };

     task.execute();

}

}
```

As I say if you remove the Thread.sleep(1000) which i'm using to simulate the json loading it works fine.

I'm using the fragment support library for 2.3 if that makes any difference.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Is `doInBackground()` ever called? And `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: I just almost copy/paste your code and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

MyFragment.this.setListAdapter(adapter);

EDIT:

Hi,

I have tried your code, even loaded the view by

```
    mLoadedFragment = new MyFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.relativeLayout, mLoadedFragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

It works fine for me, The only possible cause of the trouble should be that: the View is not visible while loading the fragment, or some similar issue.

You might want to check the layouts where you intent to load the fragment.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it still doesn't populate the list

Comment: Can you check how the fragment is loaded and where( XML). I just ran the code its working fine.

Comment: Ok that's good to know in itself. I just pulled the xml that contains my fragment up to the top level of my app and it works. Thanks I'll focus on that.

Comment: I think it's because I was inflating the xml that included that fragment in a constructor of a parent view. thanks for your help guys